# Rails - Flash message not displaying as intended using ruby case statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails app I am using various keys for flash.  Some to display a message but also some to temporarily store data.  I only want :notice, and :alert to display when present.  Here is my code.

```
  <% flash.each do |type, message| %>
    <% case type %>
    <% when :notice, :alert %>
      <% if message.is_a? Array %>
        <% message.each do |msg| %>
          <div class="alert alert-info">
            <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&#215;</a>
            <%= msg.html_safe %>
          </div>
        <% end%>
      <% else %>
        <div class="alert <%= flash_class type %>">
          <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&#215;</a>
          <%= message %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

I can't figure out why nothing is displaying.  It works fine when I remove the case statement but then every flash gets displayed which I don't want.

Comment: are you sure :notice is symbol? try like case type.to_s and also and check "notice", "alert" instead of symbols

Comment: @Thorin works with strings!  Thanks.  Couldn't find documentation that explains it, but it works.  I thought flash was a hash and so that it had to use symbols.

Comment: I have updated your code and add in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to

```
<% flash.each do |type, message| %>
    <% case type.to_s %>
    <% when "notice", "alert" %>
      <% if message.is_a? Array %>
        <% message.each do |msg| %>
          <div class="alert alert-info">
            <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&#215;</a>
            <%= msg.html_safe %>
          </div>
        <% end%>
      <% else %>
        <div class="alert <%= flash_class type %>">
          <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&#215;</a>
          <%= message %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```